# Cast increment and assign in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

How can I achieve the following? De-reference and assign a value to a pointer and increment the pointer by (uint64_t) bytes in one line.

```
// random address 0xDEADBEEF
unsigned int *myvalue = 0xDEADBEEF;
*((uint64_t*) myvalue)++ = 34;
```

An error is produced due to the casting if i remove the casting then it "works" but not with the results which I want.

```
unsigned int *myvalue = 0xDEADBEEF;
*(myvalue)++ = 34;
```

What I expect by the statement of :

```
// myvalue points to 0xDEADBEEF
*((uint64_t*) myvalue)++ = 34;
 //myvalue points to 0xDEADBEEF + (64/8)
 // at 0xDEADBEEF (a random address) should contain 34
```

Comment: no I want to derefernece it first, assign the value and then increment

Comment: Please show us what you get and what you expect. And tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you tried Increment first and then cast.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  On many non-Intel machines, your code will crash due to misaligned data access.

Comment: why is this so? do you mean the 0xdeadbeef or that if you increment a pointer by 64 bits it will be unaligned?

Comment: @denis no I have not, ill give that a go.

Comment: When you say *"increment it"* is that the pointer, or what it is pointing to?

Comment: yes its the pointer

Comment: @denis good suggestion but it doesnt work and i think it wouldnt give me the result which I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How can I] De-reference and assign a value to a pointer and increment the pointer by (uint64_t) bytes in one line[?]

You are trying to do too many things with a single expression.  You should break it up.  Moreover, "one line" is more or less arbitrary.  I could take your one-liner and spread it out over 12 non-empty lines, and I can take many lines and join them together.  The closest actually meaningful thing would be one full expression.

Nevertheless, if you insist on doing it in one full expression, and you're willing to assume that the size of an `int` evenly divides the size of a `uint64_t`, then you might do it like so:

```
unsigned int *myvalue = 0xDEADBEEF;
*myvalue = 34, myvalue += (sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(int));
```

Of course, that's mostly sophistry around the meaning of a "full expression" -- it would be much better style to use a semicolon instead of a comma operator, but then there would be two full expressions.  But that's the ground on which you chose to pitch your tent.

Alternatively, if you're open to changing the type of `myvalue`, then it would be a bit cleaner to do it like this:

```
uint64_t *myvalue = 0xDEADBEEF;
* (int *) (myvalue++) = 34;
```

Overall, however, although C permits casting from one object pointer type to another, it makes few promises about how the converted result can safely be used.  Furthermore, such casts violate the strict aliasing rule, which may contribute to an optimizing compiler producing an incorrect and hard-to-debug program.

Comment: how about the example you have given below, would that be considered as breaking the aliasing rule? Since there is a uint64_t which is then converted to an int later.

Answer (score 0):

So the subject of an increment operator needs to be a *modifiable lvalue.*

Your expression ceases to be an lvalue when you cast it.

Now, you can increment the result of the dereference with something like
`*(*x)++` ... for example, this is conforming...

```
int f(int **x)
{
  return *(*x)++;
}
```

Comment: so you are basically saying that it is not possible to do this in one line due to the cast?

Comment: so a dereference does not give an lvalue after a cast as mentioned above?

Comment: It does, yes, but the dereferenced expression wasn't what you were incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write `*(*(uint64_t**) &myvalue)++ = 34;`, but *why* would you do that?

---

Above line works because casting yields a rvalue, i.e. can only be on the right of an assignment (the assignment here is the `++`), and dereference yields a lvalue (which can be on the left).

Also, as noted by others, dereferencing your casted pointer is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Casting an `unsigned int*` to a `uint64_t*` and then dereferencing the `uint64_t*` is wrong by itself.

Disregarding that fact for a moment...

Due to operator precedence,

```
*((uint64_t*) myvalue)++ = 34;
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(((uint64_t*) myvalue)++) = 34;
```

i.e. it increments the pointer first before dereferencing it.

When you use a cast, you get an rvalue. You cannot increment or decrement an rvalue.

Also, it's not clear why you want to increment the temporary pointer obtained from the cast in the first place. Unless you have a variable that you want to use afterward, it is pointless to increment or decrement a pointer.

Comment: Dereference gives you an lvalue.

Comment: @2501 sure, which is why it's important that we determine whether he means to dereference *then* increment or vice versa

Comment: yes I would like to de-reference first, assign, then increment.

Comment: @R Sahu why is casting an unsigned int * to a uint64_t*  wrong by itself?

Comment: @Har, casting is not wrong. Dereferencing the `uint64_t*` is wrong. Lookup strict aliasing.